# Given the utility function $U(F,G)=FG^2$, find the MRS

Tags: calculus, economics

Intermediate Micro. My understanding for MRS conversions is that you find the derivative of each variable and place the former over the latter. That then in this case yields $\frac{1}{2G}$? Is this correct or is my logic misplaced here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you are right, but your (partial) derivatives seem not right.

$MRS =\frac{U_F(F,G)}{U_G(F,G)}$

$U_F(F,G)=G^{2}$

$U_G(F,G)=2F\cdot G^{}$

$\frac{U_F(F,G)}{U_G(F,G)}=\frac{G^{2}}{2F\cdot G^{}}=\frac{G}{2F}$

Is it comprehensible ? If not, feel free to ask.